# Angularjs show-hide

Tags: jquery, angularjs, show-hide, angularjs-ng-click

Im trying to re-write some of my application using angularjs.. So far i've used jQuery and made use of .show and .hide for example:

**example.html**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="home-heading">Home</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="products-heading">Products</div>
        </li>
            <li>
            <div class="about-heading">About Us</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="contact-heading">Contact us</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="home">
    Welcome to Home
</div>

<div class="products">
    Welcome to Products
</div>

<div class="about">
    Welcome to About Us
</div>

<div class="contact">
    Welcome to Contact Us
</div>
```

**show.js**

```
$('.home-heading').on('click', function() {    
    $(".home").show();
    $(".products").hide();
    $(".about").hide();
    $(".contact").hide();
});

$('.products-heading').on('click', function() {    
    $(".home").hide();
    $(".products").show();
    $(".about").hide();
    $(".contact").hide();
});

$('.about-heading').on('click', function() {    
    $(".home").hide();
    $(".products").hide();
    $(".about").show();
    $(".contact").hide();
});


$('.contact-heading').on('click', function() {    
    $(".home").hide();
    $(".products").hide();
    $(".about").hide();
    $(".contact").show();
});
```

---

Adding angular to my example.html page:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="home-heading" ng-click="showHome()">Home</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="products-heading" ng-click="showProducts()">Products</div>
        </li>
            <li>
            <div class="about-heading" ng-click="showAboutUs()">About Us</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="contact-heading" ng-click="showContact()">Contact us</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="home">
    Welcome to Home
</div>

<div class="products">
    Welcome to Home
</div>

<div class="about">
    Welcome to Home
</div>

<div class="contact">
    Welcome to Home
</div>
```

**TestController.js:**

```
require(['app'], function(app) {
app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {     

    $scope.showHome = function()     {
        alert('showHome is responding');
    };

    $scope.showProducts = function()     {
        alert('showProducts is responding');
    };

});
});
```

The correct alert messages are showing on the corresponding click, however i cannot get the corresponding DIV to show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually still use some of the same in angular. You can do something like this:

**Markup**

```
<div class="home" ng-show="ShowHomeContainer">
    Welcome to Home
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.ShowHomeContainer = false;

$scope.showHome = function(){
    $scope.ShowHomeContainer = true;
};
```

Comment: although logic makes sense, my home DIV is now always hidden.

Comment: Hmm. You did keep the ng-click on the li element? Ng-show and ng-hide bound to scope should work. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Yes i kept the ng-click on the LI

Comment: Does your clickevent reach the line that sets the property to true when clicking? I need to see what you did so far

Comment: Ive copied exactly the above and placed an alert before and after the $scope.ShowHomeContainer = true; both alerts are showing one after eachother. and the ShowHomeContainer has a display:none in the HTML when looking in Firebug

Comment: Try to reverse the bool and use ng-hide instead

Comment: Your div-containers must be withing the ng-controller div for the scope to be shared

Comment: Good suggestion, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
    <div ng-init="checked=true">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"> Is Visible...
    </label>
    <div class="check-element sample-show-hide" ng-show="checked" style="clear:both;">
      Visible...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.sample-show-hide {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide-add, .sample-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
  display:block!important;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.sample-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
  opacity:0;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide-add,
.sample-show-hide.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

You can read more here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: Thanks. Although useful, it doesnt give much advice on my issue above.